# Less css background image not found when static files are served off a sub URI

Tags: css, image, url, less

For those that are interested I'm running a Django 1.3 setup making use of the lovely static files integration and less.js.

The issue I am running into is this:

In my HTML I have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}less/style.less">
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In this case STATIC_URL is /static/ so when the HTML is processed the links become /static/less/style.less and /static/js/less.js respectively.

Now in my LESS file I have the following (simplified) code:

```
body {
    background: url('../img/bkgnd.png');
}
```

The problem is that LESS to me appears to deal with this stupidly, unless i'm being stupid, just as likely :-)

The less JS file is grabbed as http://localhost:8000/static/js/less.js and then grabs the css file at http://localhost:8000/static/less/style.less

Now I would expect that less should know the location of style.less and therefore when compiling to CSS would look for the background image at http://localhost:8000/static/less/../img/bkgnd.png which obviously is just http://localhost:8000/static/img/backgnd.png

Instead however it seems to ignore the location and just look for the background image at http://localhost:8000/img/backgnd.png.

Does anyone have an explanation why this happens?

I have added a temporary fix by setting a javascript variable containing the static url and prepending it to the image url in the css file. This is fine for development, but I want to compile the code using lessc in production and less doesn't allow me to pass in javascript variables as far as I can see (which would be nice).

Any help would be greatly appreciated, this is driving me crazy :-)

Comment: i didn't use less.js but looks like it starts outside its /js directory? what if you change the path to ../static/img/background.png ?

Answer (score 2):

It's looking for a img file in relations to the document you are viewing, not in relation to the css file.

So change your css to this:

```
body {
   background: url('/static/img/bkgnd.png');
}
```

Comment: But why is that the behaviour? Surely it would want to search for relative path images in a less file relative to where the less file lies? I haven't worked with less for very long, so maybe there is a reason for this but I am struggling to see the logic.

Comment: But this hard codes the static URL and is bad practice. If I change it in my application to /media/ then i'd have to change every instance of /static/ in my less files. I don't see this as the real issue though, I think the lack of support for variables whilst compiling is the real problem then.

Comment: Think about this like about <style> .. </style> tag directly on the page - so everything is related to the document with this tag.

Comment: I'm not sure if i'm making myself clear giker. sorry. I understand what it's doing, but i'm asking why is it doing it? Why not parse the less files intelligently and replace with relative links that make more sense? It is much less likely to see media that is located relative to a web URL, than it is to see media relative to other media (images and less/css files in this case). I think this is more a question for the creator of less, i've sent him an email.